# R/dplyr: How can I combine csv. files with different variable types?

Tags: r, merge

I have two `csv.` files:

```
CSV1:
ID V1 V2
1  2  F
2  3  D
3  2  S
4  4  V

CSV2:
ID V1 V2
5  C  2
6  D  5
7  W  8
8  G  6
```

I want to combine the two to get a data frame like this. `V1` should have both `char` and `num` data type elements.:

```
CSV_all:
ID V1 V2
1  2  F
2  3  D
3  2  S
4  4  V
5  C  2
6  D  5
7  W  8
8  G  6
```

`bind_rows(CSV1, CSV2)` gives me an error because `char` is incompatible with `num`.

Comment: Data frames allow you to combine different types of variables in separate columns but 
you cannot combine multiple variable types in the same column. In your case you have to convert the numbers in CSV1 and CSV2 to characters, e.g. `CSV_all$V1 <- as.character(CSV_all$V1)` before combining the data frames or using `rbind()` which will convert the numbers to characters.

Comment: How do I do this while importing the CSV files? I'm not creating a data frame for each of them that I could covert the variables of, but want to combine them into one big data frame.

Comment: Fair point. If you import a table that contains numerical variables, there might usually be a good reason for you to keep them as numeric. In your case you would not be able to perform any mathematical operations on your columns. If you have the need to combine data frame with different variable types you should be aware that some of them might get changed in the process. I think it makes sense to provide some background information here. Combining data frames like these feels like a very non-standard approach unless the numbers have no quantitative meaning.

Comment: Please @questionmark post one question with all the relevant info rather than a series of different questions with just little slices of your problem.  We can't help if we're guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
CSV_all <- rbind(CSV1,CSV2)
CSV_all
  ID V1 V2
1  1  2  F
2  2  3  D
3  3  2  S
4  4  4  V
5  5  C  2
6  6  D  5
7  7  W  8
8  8  G  6
```

---

With data:

```
CSV1 <- read.table( text ="
  ID V1 V2
1  2  F
2  3  D
3  2  S
4  4  V", header = T)

CSV2<- read.table( text ="
  ID V1 V2
5  C  2
6  D  5
7  W  8
8  G  6", header = T)
```

Comment: Based on OP's [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62218985/13095326), the `V1` columns of the two `.csv` files are of different classes.

Comment: Yes but unlike `bind_rows` doesn't `rbind` coerce? That's what it did using the exact same methodology as @S_t

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, sorry, but doesn't `class(CSV1$V1) != class(CSV2$V1)` ?

Comment: That's what I get one is char the other int but `rbind` forces it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))
#    ID V1 V2
#1:  1  2  F
#2:  2  3  D
#3:  3  2  S
#4:  4  4  V
#5:  5  C  2
#6:  6  D  5
#7:  7  W  8
#8:  8  G  6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, V1 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 4L), V2 = c("F", 
"D", "S", "V")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = 5:8, V1 = c("C", "D", "W", "G"), V2 = c(2L, 
5L, 8L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```